# How can I fix the back button in navigation stack while swiping back

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

[image: Broken]
[image: System Default]

So when I navigate to Settings it shows a blue Back button. But when I swipe over to go back instead of pressing it. the button wiggles all over the place.

In the iPhone settings app the back button stays in place and slowly fades based on how much I swipe. How can I do that?

also how can I rename it and change the color?

```
    import SwiftUI
    
    
    enum AppView {
        case inventory
        case settings
    }
    
    struct InventoryView: View {
        
        func navigateToSettings() {
                navigationPath = NavigationPath([AppView.settings])
            }
    
        
        var body: some View {
            
            NavigationStack(path: $navigationPath) {
                ZStack {
    
                    Image("pic1")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    
                    ScrollView {
                        
                        // Content
    
                        .navigationDestination(for: AppView.self) { view in
                            
                            switch view {
                                
                            case .inventory:
                                InventoryView()
                                
                            case .settings:
                                SettingsView()                                                            
                            }              
                         }                   
                      }
                   }
```

```
 import SwiftUI
     
     enum ActiveSheet: Identifiable {
         case option 1
         case option 2
     
         var id: Int {
             hashValue
         }
     }
     
     
     struct SettingsView: View {
         
     
         @State private var activeSheet: ActiveSheet?
         
     
         var body: some View {
             ZStack {
                 
         Image("pic1")
          .resizable()
          .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
          .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
     
                 ScrollView {
 
                     // Content
 
                     .sheet(item: $activeSheet) { item in
                         switch item {
                         case .Option 1:
                             aView()
                         case .Option 2:
                             aView()
                         }
                     }
```